# Vigenere Cipher - Java Can't get capital letters to display

Tags: java, vigenere

I am trying to get my Vigenere Cipher to work it currently prints all printable characters, however when it goes to print capital letters it will not display the correct output.

```
public class VigenereCipher {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String key = "thisIsTheKey";
    Scanner uMessage = new Scanner(System.in);
    String u = uMessage.next();
    u += uMessage.nextLine();
    String ori = u;
    String enc = encrypt(ori, key);
    System.out.println(enc);
    System.out.println(decrypt(enc, key));
}

static String encrypt(String text, String key) {
    String res = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);

        int caesar = key.charAt(i % key.length());

        int sum = c + caesar;


       if(caesar == 126){

            res += (char) (32);
        }else{
            int temp = ((sum % 126));
            if(temp < 32)
                temp += 94;
            res += (char) (temp) ;
       }

        //  j = ++j % key.length();
    }
    return res;
}




static String decrypt(String text, String key) {
    String res = "";
    // text = text.toUpperCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);

        int caesar = key.charAt(i % key.length());

           int sum = c + (126 - caesar);
        if((sum % 126) < 32)
            sum += 32;
        res += (char) (sum % 126);
    }
    return res;
}
 }
```

The program will print most thinks correctly its just when there are capital letters it will display them wrong.

For example if the user where to put in AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA with a key of "thisIsTheKey" the result of this would be this meaning if there is a capital in the key it will change the results:

```
thisIsTheKeythisIs
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
7+,6j6u+(l(<7+,6j6
AAAA!A!AA!AAAAAA!A
```

Comment: It doesn't change the result if there's a capital in the key. It changes if there's a capital in the key *and* the text to encrypt.

Comment: So how do I fix the problem of the A's that are turning into !

Comment: Debugging this should help you figure out. Possible hint: 'A' - '!' = 32

Comment: I'm just not sure where to start looking for the problem is the problem in the encryption or decryption?

Comment: Your decryption method is missing some things. First it should undo the `temp += 94` addition of the encryption with `if(c > 94) c -= 94;`. Finally it should add `94` and not 32 at `if(sum % 126) < 32)`. Or I'm not really sure, but it looks like the decryption is the problem.

Comment: So I fix the problem by adding    if (sum > 94) { sum -= 94; }  in the decryption which now prints the correct alphabet capitals but not when its done with the characters. It does the opposite now. When all !'s are added it has A's where there were ! when all A's were input